# How to write breakpoint for iphone 414px with sass?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, css

I am using sass for a current project. I want to apply sass breakpoint or media query for it. I want the code to run if the screen is 414px or below.

This is my current code:

```
@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {
.sub-menu { display: none; 
}
```

Do you know how to target 414px screen and below only? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no sass mixin available for 414px and below resolution. So we have to write our own breakpoint as follows.

```
@media (max-width: 414px) { 
   .sub-menu { 
       display: none; 
   }
 }
```

The CSS inside above media-query will apply to all screen having width 414px or lower.